# apache airflow ExternalTaskMarker clear another dag's task recursively but task state is None

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

i'm testing ExternalTaskSensor and ExternalTaskMarker.
ExternalTaskSensor wait until external Dag's Task finished and ExternalTaskMarker clear another dag's task recursively.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/external_task_sensor.html

this is my parent dag

```
# parent_dag.py

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow.sensors.external_task import ExternalTaskMarker
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

from airflow import DAG

default_args = {
    "owner": "admin",
    "retries": 0,
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=2),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='parent_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1, 9, 00, 0),
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    catchup=True
)

task_1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='echo_hello',
    bash_command='echo HELLO!!!!',
    dag=dag,

)

task_2 = ExternalTaskMarker(
    task_id='parent_trigger',
    external_dag_id='child_dag',
    external_task_id='receive_call',
    dag=dag
)

task_1 >> task_2
```

and child dag

```
# child_dag.py

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow.sensors.external_task import ExternalTaskMarker, ExternalTaskSensor
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

from airflow import DAG

default_args = {
    "owner": "admin",
    "retries": 0,
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=2)
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='child_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1, 9, 00, 0),
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    catchup=True
)

receive_call = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id='receive_call',
    external_dag_id='parent_dag',
    external_task_id='parent_trigger',
    dag=dag
)

task_1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='echo_hello',
    bash_command='echo HELLO!!!!',
    dag=dag
)

receive_call >> task_1
```

Sensor work but Marker doesn't work as i expected.

when i clear parent dag's with ExternalTaskMarker, child dag change to None state. i expected child dag will be clear and rescheduled.

do i missunderstanding about ExternalTaskSensor and ExternalTaskMarker?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have tested you script on Airflow 2.4.1. Runs successfully on LocalExecutor and SequentialExecutor.